# CSS Images Positioning and Opacity within a container

Tags: html, css

I have this html page that uses an image as its entire background. On top of that background image I have a white box with text inside and 3 images. I want the white box to be see through so the background image is still visible. But, when I change the opacity for the indexpagecontainer, the opacity for the images changes as well. Is there a way to prevent that? I also want the images to be even placed within the container I have I'm not sure how to do that without using margins and padding for all of them. Is there an easier way to do that as well? Here is my code:

```
HTML - index.html
```

```css
#indexpagecontainer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#img1 {
  float: left;
  height: 190px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#img2 {
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#img2 {
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="indexpagecontainer">

  <p id="abouttext">TEXT HERE</p>

  <img id="img1" src="images/orange.png">

  <img id="img2" src="images/apple.png">

  <img id="img2" src="images/banana.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't close your `#indexpagecontainer` div. `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this background to your css element background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5):

```
#indexpagecontainer{
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I added that and it worked thanks! Is rgba different from using opacity?

Comment: The problem is that property opacity is applied to the parent element and its childs so if you just want apply the opacity to the parent element you have to use rgba which letters mean read, green, blue, alpha(alpha is used to apply the opacity which value is between 0 and 1).